# При обращение к функции которая находится в моем классе ничего не происходит

Tags: mysqli, php

При обращение к функции которая находится в моем классе ничего не происходит пустая страница. Почему и как мне получить данные моего массива который я получаю?

```
<?    
    include('../admin/connect.php');
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
`
    `class Moderation {

            public $connect;

            function comment_query()
            {
                $comment = $this->connect->real_query('SELECT * FROM  comment WHERE moderator = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,7');
                $comment_use = $this->connect->store_result();
                $comment_fetch = $comment_use->fetch_assoc();

            }   

        }
        ?>
```

Чуть ниже в том же файле.

```
<?
    $test = $mod->comment_query();

    foreach ($test as $key => $rows) {
        echo $rows['name'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша функция (на самом деле - метод) ничего не возвращает (т.к. там нет return), поэтому в $test ничего не попадает, кроме null (непонятно, правда, почему foreach не ругается на левый аргумент).

Вам, я так понимаю, надо просто добавить следующую строчку:

```
return $comment_fetch;
```

Comment: тобиш получается в функцию записать что то на подобии return true?

Comment: @Malyshev, да, иначе (без использования глобальных переменных и передачи аргументов по ссылке, но это отдельная тема) у нее не будет никакого вывода.

Comment: ну я сделал но получается так что он возвращает всего 1 элемент массива :( попробовал через while ни чего не получилось:) но все ровно спасибо :)! удачного вам дня!

Comment: @Malyshev, так и должно быть, функции *_fetch_assoc предполагают использование в цикле (это позволяет работать с большими объемами данных, не перегружая оперативу).

    function comment_query()
    {
        $comment = $this->connect->real_query('SELECT * FROM  comment WHERE moderator = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,7');
        $comment_use = $this->connect->store_result();
        $comments = array();
        while (($comment_fetch = $comment_use->fetch_assoc()) !== false) {
            $comments[] = $comment_fetch;
        }
        return $comments;
    }

Answer (score 0):

если используете ООП то можно и через объект вернуть переменную.

```
include('../admin/connect.php');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class Moderation {

        public $connect;
        public $comment_fetch; // Добавляем переменную

        public function comment_query(){
                $comment = $this->connect->real_query('SELECT * FROM  comment WHERE moderator = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,7');
                $comment_use = $this->connect->store_result();
                // указываем что это переменная относится к нашему классу
                $this->comment_fetch = $comment_use->fetch_assoc();
            }
        }
```

Ну и само обращение:

```
// Вызываем нужный метод
$mod->comment_query();
    // В цикл передаём обращение к нашей переменной
    foreach ($mod->comment_fetch as $key => $rows) {
        echo $rows['name'];
    }
```

.